# Make jQuery UI autocomplete source dependent on another autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The problem is in the title, I don't know how to make an autocomplete widget dependent on the other. In my example, I have 2 columns in my database:

- firstName
- lastName

And some rows:

```
Dupont Francois
Dupont Oliver
Lapeche Jean
```

If I enter `Dupont` in the first autocomplete input, I want the second autocomplete to suggest `Oliver` and `Francois`, *not `Jean`*!

This is my code HTML :

```
<form action="../../controler/add/addUserDevice.php" onsubmit="return verifUserDevice(this)" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class="userLastName" name="userLastName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class="userFirstName" name="userFirstName" /</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><input class="buttonIndex" type="submit" value="Create" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my PHP code for the seconde autocomplete

```
<?php
include('../../model/connexion_sql.php');

if ((include_once '../../model/connexion_sql.php') === FALSE)
    exit('erreur include');

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $connection = new Connection;
    $connection->connection();
    $conn    = $connection->getConnection();
    $requete = $conn->prepare('SELECT userFirstName FROM user WHERE userFirstName LIKE :term');
    $requete->execute(array('term' => $_GET['term'] . '%'));
    $array = array();
    while ($donnee = $requete->fetch()) {
        $array[] = $donnee['userFirstName'];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".userFirstName").autocomplete({
        source: '../../model/autocomplete/userFirstName.php',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {   
    $(".userFirstName").autocomplete({   
        autoFocus:true,
        source: function( request, response ) {        
            $.ajax({       
                url: '../../model/autocomplete/userFirstName.php?userLastName=' + $("#userLastName").val() + "&term=" + request.term,   
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {           
                response(data);      
            }
           });   
        },    
        minLength: 1   
    });
});
```

Your ajax request will look like that.

Add `id="userLastName"` to your userLastName input.

Add this in your PHP script

```
if($_GET['userLastName']) {
    $userLastName = $_GET['userLastName'];
} else $userLastName = null;
```

then change

```
SELECT userFirstName FROM user 
WHERE userFirstName LIKE :term
```

BY

```
SELECT userFirstName FROM user 
WHERE userFirstName LIKE :term
AND (userLastName = :userLastName OR :userLastName is null)
```

Comment: It does an error :
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /var/www/base/assets/model/autocomplete/userFirstName.php:19\

Comment: I did before, this is not error, but nothing is happening to my autocomplete... Looks like there is 0 row by this request... Even if LastName is empty

Comment: It works, I got one row...
It's strange !

But my autocomplete still doesn't work

Comment: The alert in success doesn't work but the one in error works.
I've this : Use of undefined constant term - assumed 'term'
Don't know why

Comment: I forgot that and I change the order in the data :
url: '../../model/autocomplete/userFirstName.php?term=' + request.term + '&userLastName=' + $("#userLastName").val(), 
and I also forget to change my echo (that's why it was an error), but now, it works ! Really thanks you

Comment: soon you will maybe :