# How to create a Jquery autocomplete input with php that depends on a selected value from html select box?

Tags: php, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm developing a page that contains one select box (Category) and one autocomplete input (Product). In this case i would like to get the autocomplete input to load values based on a selected value from dropdownlist (Category), enabling the user to type values into autocomplete input based on selected value into dropdownlist.

For example, if i select a value into dropdownlist that call 'shoes', values related with this value will be load by input autocomplete (Product) where just will allow the user to type related values based on selected value into dropdownlist (Category).

I found some similar questions about this doubt but unfortunatly i didn't found the correctly way to improve this:

1. [PHP- Jquery Autocomplete with dynamic input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890591/php-jquery-autocomplete-with-dynamic-input-field)
2. [Make jQuery UI autocomplete source dependent on another autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324821/make-jquery-ui-autocomplete-source-dependent-on-another-autocomplete)
3. [Php autocomplete with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089733/php-autocomplete-with-jquery)
4. [PHP- Jquery Autocomplete with dynamic input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890591/php-jquery-autocomplete-with-dynamic-input-field)
5. [jQuery + PHP Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732747/jquery-php-autocomplete)

Below, i show the code where dropdownlist and autocomplete input works fine:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
<br>
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Select Category</label>

<?php

include 'db.php';
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<select name="categoryFK" id="categoryFK" class="form-control">
  <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['categoryID']; ?>"><?= $row['category']; ?></option>  
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>

</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Type Product</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="products"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">        
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#products").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
    });
});
</script>

</body>
```

And below is the php script that make autocomplete input works:

```
<?php 
// Database configuration 
$dbHost     = "localhost"; 
$dbUsername = "root"; 
$dbPassword = ""; 
$dbName     = "test"; 

// Create database connection 
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName); 

// Check connection 
if ($db->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error); 
} 

// Get search term 
$searchTerm = $_GET['term']; 

// Fetch matched data from the database 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'"); 

// Generate array with skills data 
$productData = array(); 
if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $data['productID'] = $row['productID']; 
        $data['value'] = $row['productName']; 
        array_push($productData, $data); 
    } 
} 

// Return results as json encoded array 
echo json_encode($productData); 
?>
```

As described above, both, dropdownlist and autocomplete input works just fine but i would like to know how can i improve the code above to make autocomplete input related with selected dropdownlist value?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
    $("#products").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    category : $( "#categoryFK option:selected" )
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
    $category = $_GET['category'];

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND category = '$category'");
```

Comment: Hi Axel. Thanks for your feedback. I tried as you said, but i got this error on Chrome debug: `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.k.param (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>.source (index.php:57)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>._search (jquery-ui.min.js:8)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>._search (jquery-ui.min.js:6)`.